# 'Last Viewed By' Account field test - System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'null'

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, class

Trying to create a Last Viewed By field on Account. I'm newbish at Apex and not seeing what I'm missing here... I'm sure it's a rookie mistake. Adapting code from http://www.sfdcpanther.com/setting-up-last-viewed-by-in-salesforce/ .... formatted this post as best I could!

**Stack trace:**
    Class.LastViewedByController_Test.updateField_Test: line 15, column 1

### VF Component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="LastViewedByController"  allowDML="true">


<script>
   window.onload=function(){
     doInit();
   };
</script>

<apex:attribute name="Account" type="String" assignTo="{!Name}"
               description="Object Name on which VF is developed"
               access="global" required="true" />

<apex:attribute name="Last Viewed By" type="String" assignTo="{!Last_Viewed_By}"
               description="Field API name where you need to show the Last Viewed By"
               access="global" required="true" />

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="doInit" action="{!updateField}" reRender=""/>
</apex:form>

</apex:component>
```

---

### Controller Class

```
public class lastViewedByController{

public Datetime cDT;
public String LongDate;
public String firstname;
public String lastname;

// objectName = TestAccount


public static String TestAccount { get; set; }
public static String Last_Viewed_By { get; set; }
public static String Name { get; set; }

public lastViewedByController(){

}

public String getLongDate() {
    cDT = System.now(); //Format the datetime value to your locale
    LongDate = cDT.format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    return LongDate;
}

public void updateField() {
    // Get the user info from the current user
    firstname = System.Userinfo.getFirstName();
    lastname  = System.Userinfo.getLastName();
    Name = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    String fieldQuery = String.format('SELECT Id, {} FROM TestAccount WHERE Id = :Name', new List<String> { Last_Viewed_By });

    //System.debug('#### Query  '+fieldQuery );
    Account objectToUpdate = Database.Query(fieldQuery);

    objectToUpdate.put(Last_Viewed_By, (firstname + ' ' + lastname + ', ' + getLongDate()));
    //System.debug('#### objectToUpdate '+objectToUpdate);
    update objectToUpdate;

}

}
```

### Controller Test

```
@isTest
private class LastViewedByController_Test {
@testSetup
public static void generateTestData(){
    Account acc = new Account (Name = 'Last_Viewed_By');
    insert acc;
}
public static testMethod void updateField_Test(){
    Test.startTest();
        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.LastViewedBy);
        LastViewedByController.TestAccount = 'Account';
        LastViewedByController.Last_Viewed_By = 'Last Viewed By';
    lastViewedByController contr = new lastViewedByController();
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>([Select Id, Name From Account      Where Name = 'Last Viewed By' LIMIT 1]);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', accList[0].Id);
    //LastViewedByController.Name = accList[0].Id;
    contr.updateField();
    Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void updateField() {
    // Get the user info from the current user
    firstname = System.Userinfo.getFirstName();
    lastname  = System.Userinfo.getLastName();
    Name = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    String fieldQuery = 'Select Id, '+Last_Viewed_By +' From '+Account +' Where Id = '+'\''+Name+'\'';
```

I understand why you are using Dynamic SOQL here, but be aware you can still use dynamic binding and string templating in Dynamic SOQL to make it much safer and easier to construct.

Here, you could do

```
String fieldQuery = String.format('SELECT Id, {} FROM Account WHERE Id = :Name', new List<String> { Last_Viewed_By });
```

Based on your current code, you do not need (and do not use) the variable `Account`. I suspect that's your `null` here, and it's why SOQL is confused when you concatenate it into your query.

Note that SOQL binding (`:`) also guards you against injection attacks, and the `id` parameter you are using here is under the user's control. Further, you won't have to deal with adding quotes in string concatenation.

You've got some issues with variable scoping and namespace collisions.

```
public static String Account { get; set; }
```

Naming this variable `Account`, the name of a built-in sObject, is legal but likely to cause confusion.

You're also going back and forth between `UppercaseVariableName` and `Snake_Name` and `lowername`, which can add a little confusion. While Apex is case-insensitive, it's somewhat common to do `camelCaseVariables` and `UpperCamelTypes`, with custom fields being either `UpperCamelField__c` or `Upper_Snake_Field__c`. Naming conventions just help you keep straight what you're talking about throughout your code.

Comment: Thank you for the education! I'm stuck again, but this time the error is:  System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0  . Stack trace: Class.LastViewedByController_Test.updateField_Test: line 15, column 1 .... I've updated the code above with my edits since your post. I appreciate you!

Comment: Your query's got a wrong parameter. Look at the `Name` fields carefully :) Also, just a note - it can be confusing if you change your code in a question in response to answers. The answer will no longer make sense to other readers. For substantive follow-ups, consider opening a new question.

Comment: I've been banging on this, changing names one at a time and failing tests for about six hours in total. A monkey on a keyboard would have had better results... may I please ask for a little more guidance? I'm self-teaching and my teacher isn't very good. I've been flipping between controller, test, and component for so long that it's all a haze now, and I just snapped at my roommate for interrupting with cookies. COOKIES! Clearly this is a crisis... ;((( Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I meant to be playful rather than obtuse. Your test creates an account called Last_Viewed_By with underscores and queries for Last Viewed By without underscores.

Comment: I actually appreciate the Socratic method (no pun intended)! I'm disappointed in my inability to see the picture clearly when the individual components (again, no pun... yeah...) aren't challenging. I'm going to study this out on a less stressed mind- you took the time to teach me something, the least I could do is learn it!  8^)  Thank you so much!! I gave you a green checkmark, I'll figure out how to properly close this when rested

Comment: I'm a Platonist, so that's appropriate. Accepting the answer (green check) is all you need to do to indicate your question is solved.